# golang mysql driver failing at parameter replacement

Tags: mysql, database, go, driver

OS Mojave, 
MySQL v8.0.15,
go 1.12.3 darwin/amd64

```
import (
    "database/sql"

    // import mysql driver anonymously (just run the init)
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
)

...

_, err = db.db.Exec("USE ?", "test")
if err != nil {
    return errors.Wrapf(err, "error selecting database %s", opt.Database)
}

_, err = db.db.Prepare("SELECT value FROM ? WHERE key = ?")
if err != nil {
    return errors.Wrap(err, "error generating SELECT statement")
}
```

The error I get is `error selecting database test: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1`

I get the same error (about syntax around '?') for any parameter replacement I attempt to do. I've checked the manual as well as tutorials and examples I've found online and can't quite tell what I'm doing wrong.

If I replace the '?'s with values (strings) then everything works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Question marks `?` in prepared statements are for values, not table, database or column names.

Use `fmt.Sprintf` to fill in the database structure related values.

Example:

```golang
_, err := db.db.Prepare(fmt.Sprintf("SELECT value FROM %s WHERE key = ?", table))
```